# Dictionary to Dataframe Error: "If using all scalar values, you must pass an index"

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

Currently, I am using a for loop to read csv files from a folder.
After reading the csv file, I am storing the data into one row of a dictionary.
When I print the data types using "print(list_of_dfs.dtypes)" I receive:

dtype: object
DATETIME : object
VALUE : float64
ID : int64
ID Name: object.

Note that this is a nested dictionary with thousands of values stored in each of these data fields. I have 26 rows of the structure listed above. I am trying to append the dictionary rows into a dataframe where I will have only 1 row consisting of the datafields:

Index DATETIME VALUE ID ID Name.

Note: I am learning python as I go.
I tried using an array to store the data and then convert the array to a dataframe but I could not append the rows of the dataframe.

Using the dictionary method I attempted "df = pd.Dataframe(list_of_dfs)"
This throws an error.

```
list_of_dfs = {} 

for I in range(0,len(regionLoadArray)
list_of_dfs[I] = pd.read_csv(regionLoadArray[I]) 

#regionLoadArray contains my- file names from list directory.

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dfs)
#this method was suggested at thispoint.com for nested dictionaries.
#This is where my error occurs^
```

> ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

I appreciate any assistance with this issue as I am new to python.
My current goals is to simply produce a dataframe with my Headers that I can then send to a csv.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occurs because pandas needs an index. At first this seems sort of confusing because you think of list indexing. What this is essentially asking for is a column number for each dictionary to correspond to each dictionary. You can set this like so:

```
import pandas as pd
list = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
df = pd.DataFrame(list, index = [0, 1, 2, 3])
```

The data frame then yields:

```
   0  
0 'a'
1 'b'
2 'c'
3 'd'
```

For you specifically, this might look something like this using numpy (not tested):

```
list_of_dfs = {} 

for I in range(0,len(regionLoadArray)):
    list_of_dfs[I] = pd.read_csv(regionLoadArray[I]) 

ind = np.arange[len(list_of_dfs)]

dataframe = pd.DataFrame(list_of_dfs, index = ind)
```

Comment: I attempted adding the index as described above by introducing the index array and assigning the value in my for loop: "index[I] = I" and finally generating the dataframe using the index. However I receive the error message: " shape of passed values is {0} , indices imply {1}.format(passed,implied)

Comment: @Lonsdale_Energy, it needs the entire list. See my edits.

Comment: I assume np is numpy. error "modules 'numpy' has no attribute 'arrange' "

Comment: Ah, this is a typo. It should be 'arange'. Yes, np is numpy. I have changed the answer.

Comment: Gotcha, I should have figured that one out. That worked but now I have the error: "built+in_function_or_method' object is not subscriptable.

Comment: len is a built in function. It sounds like you copied and pasted in my code directly. This is why I put '(not tested).' I forgot a '):' at the end end of the for loop. I do not know if there are other typos since it is hard for me to test. You should be familiar enough with len().

Comment: I am familiar with len and no I did not copy your loop, there is more to my code that is unrelated to the question. It seems like the issue lies within the use of len.

Comment: The question was originally about why you were getting the 'pass an index error.' Without knowing more about the rest of your code, it is hard to say. I think I answered the original question, if it was helpful, you can mark as accepted by hitting the green check.

Answer (score 26):

Depending on your needs, a simple workaround could be:

```
dct = {'col1': 'abc', 'col2': 123}
dct = {k:[v] for k,v in dct.items()}  # WORKAROUND
df = pd.DataFrame(dct)
```

which results in

```
print(df)

  col1  col2
0  abc   123
```

Answer (score 15):

Pandas unfortunately always needs an index when creating a DataFrame.
You can either set it yourself, or use an object with the following structure so pandas can determine the index itself:

```
    data= {'a':[1],'b':[2]}
```

Since it won't be easy to edit the data in your case,

A hacky solution is to wrap the data into a list

```
    dataframe = pd.DataFrame([list_of_dfs])
```

Comment: The hacky solution was a clever one! Not sure if there are any caveats though.

Comment: Can someone explain why this works?

Comment: @NathanDai   it is because a list type inherently has an index. So putting data without an index into a list element gives it an index. Pandas Dataframe requires the data to have an index.

Answer (score 5):

```
import pandas as pd

d = [{"a": 1, "b":2, "c": 3},
    {"a": 4, "b":5, "c": 6},
    {"a": 7, "b":8, "c": 9}
]

pd.DataFrame(d, index=list(range(len(d))))
```

returns:

```
   a    b   c
0   1   2   3
1   4   5   6
2   7   8   9
```